# Finding rows with the same values in another column and concatenating them in a separate column

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, duplicates

I have a dataset that includes `IDs` of different products with an assigned factory number to them.
My goal is to create a column to track what products have the same assigned number. This is a summary of the data.

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,a,b,d),
           number=c("178","321","178","452","984","321","540","178","321","452"))
df %>% glimpse()
```

```
Rows: 8
Columns: 2
$ id     <dbl> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2
$ number <chr> "178", "321", "178", "452", "984"~
```

What I would like to have in the outcome is :

```
ID      shared product     what products
 a            1                a,c
 b            1                b,f
 c            1                a,c
 d            0                 
 e            0
 f            1                b,f
 g            0
```

`shared product` is a binary column that indicates if that item has a same number with any of the other products. And the `what products` column indicates what those products are.

I hope it makes sense to you!

Thank you so much in advance!

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `group_by` + `mutate` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df |>
  group_by(number) |>
  mutate(
    shared_product = +(length(id) > 1),
    what_products = if_else(shared_product > 0,
      paste(unique(id), collapse = ","),
      NA_character_
    )
  ) |>
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>   id    number shared_product what_products
#>   <chr> <chr>           <int> <chr>        
#> 1 a     178                 1 a,c          
#> 2 b     321                 1 b,f          
#> 3 c     178                 1 a,c          
#> 4 d     452                 0 <NA>         
#> 5 e     984                 0 <NA>         
#> 6 f     321                 1 b,f          
#> 7 g     540                 0 <NA>         
#> 8 a     178                 1 a,c          
#> 9 b     321                 1 b,f
```

Comment: Thanks! can you please explain what ```length(id) > 1``` does?

Comment: First, `length(id)` is just the verbose way of using `n()` as the others answers did. And it simply checks whether we have more than one element or product per `number`group.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr) # version>=1.1.0

unique(df) %>% 
   mutate(shared = +(n()>1),
          products = ifelse(shared, toString(id), ''), .by=number)

  id number shared products
1  a    178      1     a, c
2  b    321      1     b, f
3  c    178      1     a, c
4  d    452      0         
5  e    984      0         
6  f    321      1     b, f
7  g    540      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
df %>% 
 distinct() %>% 
  mutate(shared = +(n() > 1),
   products = case_when(as.logical(shared) ~ toString(id), 
  TRUE ~ ""), .by = number)
```

-output

```
  id number shared products
1  a    178      1     a, c
2  b    321      1     b, f
3  c    178      1     a, c
4  d    452      0         
5  e    984      0         
6  f    321      1     b, f
7  g    540      0
```

Comment: Thanks! can you please explain what ```+(n() > 1``` does?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples, one using summarize and another using mutate.
I modified your "shared_product" column to a simple count which makes more sense to me.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(id=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","a","b"),
                 number=c("178","321","178","452","984","321","540","178","321"))
df %>% glimpse()
df %>% str() 
df <- df %>% mutate(id=as.factor(id),
              number=as.factor(number))
df %>% str()

df %>% group_by(number) %>% mutate(
  count_number = n(),
  which_products = paste0(id,collapse = ",")
) 

df %>% group_by(id,number) %>% summarise(
  which_products = str_c(id,collapse = ",")
  
)
```